# jQuery set call back on child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to attach an onChange callback to all the input elements under the div `#dim`. It selects all 3 input elements, but returns an exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'change'
```

It may be because `x` may not be a jQuery object. How would I make this work?

```
function registercb() {
    var sel = $("div.dim > input");
    for (x in sel) {
        x.change(function() {
            dosomething();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
function registercb() {
   $("div.dim > input").change(dosomething);               
}
```

A few things to watch for:

- Inside that *iteration* (don't use this, see the next point) `x` is the DOM element, not a jQuery object which has the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method, you would need to wrap it in a jQuery object like `$(x)`, but again that isn't the correct solution here.
- Don't use a `for(...in...)` loop to *iterate* an object (a jQuery object is array-like), that type of loop is for *enumeration*.
- Most jQuery functions (almost *all*) run on more than one element, so just run it on the set to affect all elements, [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) is one of these.
- In the cases you *do* need to loop, check out [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), as it'll make your life much easier, **don't use this here**, it's only an example of what it would look like:

Example:

```
function registercb() {
   $("div.dim > input").each(function() {
      $(this).change(dosomething);               
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop over the elements. You can think of a jQuery object as holding a collection. When you do:

```
var sel = $("div.dim > input");
```

It means that `sel` has all the input elements in it, so then when you run a method like change() it will affect all of the elements in the collection. Thus you can do something like this:

```
function registercb() {
  $("div.dim > input").change(function(){
    dosomething();
  });
}
```

**Bonus knowledge:** Now your problem is that when you were doing `for( x in sel )` you are getting a lot of stuff on the jQuery object itself that you don't want. If you run the  following code in chrome you'll see it outputting a lot unexpected stuff:

```
for( x in sel ){
  console.log( x );
}
```

Instead jQuery has the `each` that lets you loop over the things you want:

```
sel.each(function(index, item){
  console.log(item);
});
```

You can even use it on other things, which is really handy!

```
$([1,2,3]).each(function( index item ){
  console.log( item );  // 1,2,3
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `'dim'` `div` has an ID rather than a class of `dim`, you can simply do this:

```
$("#dim > input").change(function() { dosomething(); });
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/Fg36J/).

In the text you refer to `#dim` whereas in the code you're refering to `.dim` - `#` selects by ID and `.` selects by class, so if your div is in the format `<div id="dim">` then you won't find any matched elements with `div.dim` as your selector.